# Hide div if span is empty

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to hide *First class* if `prop-value` is empty. Any ideas on how to do that? Basically hide the whole div if Prop-value is empty

```
<div>
  <span class='prop-name'>First:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class='prop-value'>_#= EBITDA =#_</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This assumes you have more than one, but will work for a single one as well

```
$(".prop-value").each(function(){ 
    if($(this).html().trim()==="") $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Target all empty spans, get the parent div, and hide it

```js
$('.prop-value:empty').closest('div').hide();
```

```css
div {position: relative;height: 30px;width: 200px;background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <span class='prop-name'>First:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <span class='prop-value'>Not empty</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class='prop-name'>Second:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <span class='prop-value'><!-- is empty --></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
if($(".class_to_check_if_empty").html()==""){
    $(".class_to_hide").hide();
}
```

```css
.class_to_hide{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class='class_to_check_if_empty'></div>
<div class='class_to_hide'></div>
```